# What timezone is used for financial data returned in Google Sheets

Tags: google-finance

Using =`GoogleFinance("EURUSD","price",StartDate,EndDate)` produces two columns of results:

The date and the currency rate on that date. Great! Except that it's unclear what timezone it is using.

I tried changing the timezone of the sheet `(File -> Spreadsheet settings)` but when I re-ran the formula the data did not change at all. ie. with the spreadsheet set to London time it says `EURUSD` closed at 1.17093 on the 23rd May 2018 at 23:58.

But when I change the spreadsheet to New York time and re-ran the formula it still says `EURUSD` closed at 1.17093 on the 23rd May 2018 at 23:58.

So if the date/time is independent of the sheet settings, then what timezone is it using?

Comment: My guess would be UTC. Do you have a reason to suspect otherwise?

Comment: Yes, it appears that all FX is UTC. Separately there's an error in the timestamp for stocks. For example if you pull in the Opening price of a UK stock it says 16:00 in the timestamp, which is wrong, it should be 08:00.

Comment: [tag:google-spreadsheet]?